# Get current location every n minutes in android

Tags: java, android, location, android-gps, user-location

I want to get the `latitude` and `longitude` every n minutes and then use them in my app for setting the user in an area. The only problem is that I don't know how to get the `location` every -let's say- 2 minutes.

PS: I'm using both `GPS` and `WiFi`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you please have a better title and more detailed information in the content with your effort to solve the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just adjust it according to your need.

```
    Timer timer = new Timer ();
    TimerTask hourlyTask = new TimerTask () {
    @Override
    public void run () {
        // check if GPS enabled
        GPSTracker gpsTracker = new GPSTracker(this);
        if (gpsTracker.getIsGPSTrackingEnabled()){
            String stringLatitude = String.valueOf(gpsTracker.latitude);
            String stringLongitude = String.valueOf(gpsTracker.longitude);
            }
        }
    };

// schedule the task to RUN every hour
timer.schedule (hourlyTask, 0l, 1000*60*60);   // 1000*10*60 every 10 minut
```